# how to view node js from localhost with https

Tags: javascript, node.js, geolocation

i have geolocation js on some local node server page
am tryting to view it from another device on the same network

the problem is since it is geo location js it needs to be on https
when viewd
it shows `This site can’t provide a secure connectionlocalhost sent an invalid response.`

`ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Comment: Use a tunnel program (free) like https://ngrok.com/ or [cloudflared/argo tunnel](https://blog.cloudflare.com/tunnel-for-everyone/)

Comment: problem got fixed

Comment: used openssl on gitbash from windows to get new ssl certificate and that solved it thank you